Varimax - strange values of Proportion Var
I'm trying to calculate the rotation of loadings in R using the varimax function. I only use the first 5 components (eigenvalue > 1). I understand that the proportion variance will be different from the variance of the unrotated components. I would expect that in the case of 5 components and normalized SS loadings will be equal to 0.2 for each component. But in my case it is only 0.067, so it looks like it is still calculated from all 15 components. Od did I  lose the quality of components?
I am using this code for rotation:
rotated_loadings <- varimax(q_pca$rotation[,1:5], normalize = TRUE)$loadings
print(rotated_loadings)





PC1
PC2
PC3
PC4
PC5




SS loadings
1.000
1.000
1.000
1.000
1.000


Proportion Var
0.067
0.067
0.067
0.067
0.067


Cumulative Var
0.067
0.133
0.200
0.267
0.333



